# Borrow from or borrow to someone?

Tags: prepositions

I made an English test and the question was:

> While waiting for my paycheck, could I please borrow ...
>   A: money to you
>   B: you money
>   C: money from you
>   D: money at you

The correct answer is given as *money to you* (A). But I disagree with this answer. I think it is "Could I please borrow money from you".

Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: You are correct, "I **borrow** money **from** you."  If it's the other way around, then you use a different verb: "I **lend** money **to** you."

Answer (score 3):

You always *borrow from X*.

The opposite of *borrow* is *lend* - you *lend to X*.

*To X* identifies the target of an action if X is not an infinitive.  *From X* is used to identify X as the source or starting point of something.  So you can't mix these up without changing the meaning.

I've heard *borrow to X* as a synonym for *lend to X*, not sure how widespread this is in the US.

Comment: For most US speakers, "borrow to" would only be understood because of the context, and we would think the speaker was either an English learner or using some very unusual dialect.